# I've unprotected acceptive oral sex with 3 partners, two of which were from escort service. What are my chances to get some desease(s)?

Tags: procedural-expectations, sti, sexual-penetration, oral-sex

I've unprotected oral sex with 3 partners, two of which were from escort service while I was in not sober state. It was a gay sex (I'm usually rather straight and it was my almost first gay experience) and I was acceptive part. No-one ejaculated in my mouth though but penetration was deep in the throat.

I highly regret about that.

I'm scared so much that now I have some desease and can't take tests because mite biten me and now I have to take 2 weeks antibiotics course to prevent LIme desease(s) and then I need to wait for 2 weeks more before taking the tests.
How high chances of getting some desease?
Which tests should I take and how?
I feel like I'm going crazy.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen a doctor? If not, delaying will only make things worse IMHO. // What other research have you done to find answers?

Comment: For example, did you already review the top 5-10 sites here? https://www.google.com/search?q=std+risk&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS650US654&oq=std+risk

Comment: In a nutshell, the "serious" things e.g. STD's are transferred only by fluids, so if there was no ejaculation you should be safe, but really better go see a doctor as other comment here adviced.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This is not medically accurate!  Pre-ejaculate is a body fluid that can carry HIV!  Also syphilis, gonorrhea, chlamydia, HPV, etc...all can be transmitted by contact with or without "body fluids."

Answer (score 3):

I would encourage you to get seen by a healthcare professional for testing/advice. This could be from your family doctor or at a walk-in clinic. There might also be a sexual health center near you that can offer testing, advice, and counseling services. Everything would be confidential and should be judgement free (if you feel like you are being judged you can always ask to see someone else).